# Jpanel in a JScrollPane, drawing over scroll bars

Tags: java, swing, custom-controls, jscrollpane, graphics2d

I have a problem as shown in the picture

[image: Drawing overlays scrollbars]

My procedure of adding is as follows:

JFrame -> View Panel -> JTabbedPane -> JPanel (My Canvas)

I draw my drawings inside paintComponent, and calls revalidate() at the very end. Help would be highly appreciated!

Edit:

paintComponent code

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);        
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    //Obtain document size
    double width = model.getWidth();
            double height = model.getHeight();

    canvasBounds = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fill(canvasBounds);

    Dimension size = new Dimension();
    size.setSize(canvasBounds.getWidth() * zoomFactor, canvasBounds.getHeight() * zoomFactor);
    this.setPreferredSize(size);

    g2d.setClip(canvasBounds);
    List<DrawableShape> svgShapes = model.getDrawableShapes();
    for(DrawableShape shape : shapeList) {
        shape.draw(g2d);            
    }           
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your code for `paintComponent()`

Comment: What you are trying to achieve make me think of this Oracle tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#update . Maybe it can help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (Note: SSCCE!='your code'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved. I had to compare the clipping on my canvasBounds with the g2d.getClipBounds(). Since my canvasBounds clip was much bigger than what was g2d given, it drew at the scroll bar.

Thank you your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is not obeying the bounds of your `clip`. Maybe it is being changed in the `shape.draw()` method?

Why don't you try creating a new Graphics object to pass to `shape.draw()`, instead of your `setClip()`. Something like this...

```
Graphics2D newG = (Graphics2D)g.create(0, 0, width, height);
```

And then change your code to this...

```
shape.draw(newG);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you should try to get your frames JRootPane object , iterate down to your Components Level and retreieve your components bounds with getBounds() , and then add this Rectangles to your clipping mask. That way your paint will look like its behind your components and not above it.

Recently I came up with the same problem. I solved this way :

```
    Rectangle mask = null;


for( Component c : getComponents() )

{

    if( c instanceof JRootPane )

    {

        JRootPane rootPane = (JRootPane) c;

        rootPane.setDoubleBuffered(true);

        for( Component cRootPane : rootPane.getComponents())

        {

             if( cRootPane instanceof JLayeredPane)

             {

                JLayeredPane cLayerPanels = (JLayeredPane) cRootPane;

                cLayerPanels.setDoubleBuffered(true);

                for( Component cLayerPanel : cLayerPanels.getComponents() )

                {

                    if( cLayerPanel instanceof JPanel)

                    {

                        JPanel cPanels = (JPanel) cLayerPanel;

                        cPanels.setDoubleBuffered(true);



                        for( Component cPanel : cPanels.getComponents() )

                        {

                            if( cPanel instanceof JPanel)

                            {

                                JPanel cPanels2 = (JPanel) cPanel;

                                cPanels2.setDoubleBuffered(true);

                                 mask = getBounds();

                                for( Component cPanel2 : cPanels2.getComponents() )

                                {

                                    mask.union(cPanel2.getBounds());

                                    cPanel2.paint(cPanel2.getGraphics());

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

getGraphics().setClip(mask);
```